# FMDB not building iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, sqlite, fmdb

I am installing fmdb SQLite wrapper for iOS. I cloned the git repo, and copied the `/src` and `/extra` directories into my project. I added the target dependency and the .a static library to my build phase in Xcode. When building, I get:

```
ARC Semantics:
my_app_path/src/fmdb.m:160:24: No known instance method for selector 'isEqualTo:'
```

I'm building for iOS 6.1. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is to remove `fmdb.m` from your project; it's a series of tests for fmdb and isn't required for normal usage.

The better answer is to add fmdb to your xcodeproj as a dependency and link against the static library that it will build.